# how to support landscape/Portrait orientation only for one UIView

Tags: iphone

I'm having 5 view controllers in my navigation based application, I need to support both landscape/Portrait mode in only a one view, following items displaying in the view
Navigationbar
Tool bar with two buttons
UIImageView in center.
UILabe below the navigaton bar.

Can any one help me how to support the orientation change to only for this view.

Regards,

sam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation** in your view controller, and return **YES** for view controllers that should support both Landscape/Portrait

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:

Comment: well i override the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: to return the "YES", but no luck, i only need one view to support the landscape/Portrait orientation...,so i did not override the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in other view controllers.

Comment: I guess your case is : "All child view controllers in your UITabBarController or UINavigationController do not agree on a common orientation set.

To make sure that all your child view controllers rotate correctly, you must implement shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation for each view controller representing each tab or navigation level. Each must agree on the same orientation for that rotate to occur. That is, they all should return YES for the same orientation positions." http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1688.html

Comment: I think you should rotate manually with self.view.transform. And getting rotation alerts by deviceNotifications.