# Change Orientation to landscape for a UIView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a `UINavigationController`-based app that only supports portrait, but need to push one view that requires landscape.  I've found [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003786/how-to-support-landscape-portrait-orientation-only-for-one-uiview) that describes how to allow mixed rotations for a single view, but what is the process for **forcing** a single view, when pushed, to be in landscape then returning the app to portrait mode when the view is popped.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot force an orientation change just by pushing onto the nav stack.  What you can do instead is present the view controller which must be landscape as a modal view controller instead.