# Autorotate video played from UIWebView to landscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView, filled this way :

```
[myWebView loadHTMLString:@"<iframe src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/grTCDFbhKMU\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
baseURL:nil];
```

The video is correctly launched, but it's not possible to switch to landscape mode.

I already wrote this in the concerned ViewController :

```
- (void)didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[notification object] orientation];

    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        [self.newsContent setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2.0)];
    }
    else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        [self.newsContent setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / -2.0)];
    }
    else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        [self.newsContent setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI)];
    }
    else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        [self.newsContent setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0)];
    }
}
```

Usefull to change content orientation, but usesless once the video launched :(

Any ideas ?

Comment: Same problem why, webView doesn't play video from youtube in landscape mode... I tried subclass webview with method for rotate to landsc

Answer (score 0):

You should return YES in the following method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation { 

    //All orientations are accepted except for the upsidedown orientation
    if(interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

If YES is returned it will rotate, if no is returned it will not rotate.

Comment: I already tried it. It doesn't work. Moreover, I'v read this method must be implemented for every ViewController in the app to make it work. And I don't want to autorotate the entire app.

Comment: You can return NO in other cases if you dont want to rotate. However it rotated for me after using this.

Comment: I've tried to add the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method in all of my ViewController. However, I can't return NO in all of my ViewController and YES in only one. Autorotation won't work.

Comment: Strange, then i suppose something is interfering with this method. I'm not sure what it could be since it works perfectly for me when i add this to the viewcontroller i want to rotate.

Comment: I guess it's because I am using UITabBarController. Check at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003786/how-to-support-landscape-portrait-orientation-only-for-one-uiview/4003829#4003829