# Ipad in landscape mode and iphone in portrait mode

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, landscape, portrait

I need to set `Portrait` mode when my application is running in a `iPhone` and in `Landscape` mode when running in `iPad`.
I have change in `info.plist` but i can't set it for `iPad` or `iPhone`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your `project target`, go to `General`, then in the `Development Info` section follow the attached images:

1-Make sure that your app is set to `Universal` for the supported devices

2-Chose iPhone and check Portrait.

3-Chose iPad and check Landscape.

[image: iPhone Portrait]
[image: iPad Landscape]

Comment: now its don't have this options in xcode 9.2 please tell what to do for this situation.?

Comment: Although 9.2 don't have this option. you can still firstly select ipad in "devices" and select orientation, and then select "iphone" and select orientation. Afterwards, you select back to "universal" in devices. The orientation of iphone and ipad will follow what you have selected before.

Answer (score 8):

In Xcode 9.2 have no option for selecting the orientation for ipad and iphone

[image]

but we can able to change it in by info.plist  whatever orientation we should need.. its much easy too.

[image]

Reference : [iPhone portrait-only app starts as landscape on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38520699/iphone-portrait-only-app-starts-as-landscape-on-ipad)

Answer (score -2):

Check here for iPad:

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/134746/use-only-portrait-mode-on-ipad

and here for iPhone:
[how to support landscape/Portrait orientation only for one UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003786/how-to-support-landscape-portrait-orientation-only-for-one-uiview)

Just a quick google..

Comment: of course, if it´s portrait or landscape doesn´t matter, just change the value.