# iPhone portrait-only app starts as landscape on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, orientation

I have an iOS app with the following settings:

Devices: iPhone

Device orientation: Portrait

When I start on a landscape-oriented iPad, however, it shows the launch screen in landscape mode (not properly resized), and the main screen x/y coordinates get switched within  viewDidLoad (although the main screen appears in portrait). This does not happen when I run it on iPhone.

Any idea how to prevent it? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to be as specific as possible in my question. There is no custom programming associated with the launch screen...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at you app's info.plist file:

[image]

Change the config if need.